# winsound not playing sound

Tags: python, path, winsound

I am trying to use winsound, but it just plays the default OS sound, meaning it cant find the path. Is there something wrong with my path? I have already tried double slashes and raw string.

```
winsound.PlaySound('"C:\\Users\\Admin\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python_Projects\\Yukan_no_Shonen_Red_Number.mp3"',winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use double backslash ('\\') to provide any kind of path in Python strings. And, by doing a quick search it seems like playsound doesn't like paths with spaces in them, so my suggestion would be to try and specify the path between double quotes like this `'"full_path"'`.

Comment: as i said, i have already tried double backslash, but it still is playing the default sound.

Comment: No, you said you tried double slash, not **back**slash.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion too, still playing the default sound. i have tested finding the path with pathlib, and it found it. still wondering how winsound cant find it.

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem with spaces in your pathname. Try doing the suggestion I added to the answer...

Comment: I have updated the path. Please check if i did it right, because its still playing the default sound

Comment: If you removed whitespaces from the path, then there's no need of surrounding it with double quotes. Try to use the path you updated without the "". If it still doesn't work, maybe you typed your path incorrectly.